# Converting Scorm's lesson_location into its xAPI equivalent

Tags: scorm, xapi

I have a SCORM package which stores the current location the learner is on the content as follows

```
API.LMSSetValue("cmi.core.lesson_location", currentPage);
```

I would want set the current location of the user in its tin Can Xapi version as well.

But I am confused verb is visiting a read only content page
**Completed , Mastered or experienced ?**

& what Activity could thatverb be associated with

Some one may answer please ....

Comment: [https://xapi.com/bookmarklet/](https://xapi.com/bookmarklet/)  is this the answer ???

Answer (score 1):

ADL created a [SCORM Profile](https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-SCORM-Profile/blob/master/xapi-scorm-profile.md) for xAPI. Its purpose is to give people using SCORM a way to convert that data to xAPI. Some of it can be converted into xAPI statements like your completed statement above. These statements tend to describe actions the learner is taking in the content (success, completion, answered a question, played a video).

Other SCORM data isn't as much about the learner as about the content, such as lesson_location. That stuff doesn't fit well in a statement. So xAPI also has API endpoints for this other stuff like [activity state](https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-Spec/blob/master/xAPI-Communication.md#stateres) and activity profile information. The SCORM Profile uses activity state in xAPI to store that information because lesson_location is describing the state of the activity, see the [lesson_location description](https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-SCORM-Profile/blob/master/xapi-scorm-profile.md#location) in the SCORM Profile.

Hopefully that helps. As for your bookmarklet link, that is a small script you can bookmark in your browser that will post a statement that you visited that page, not a script that can be used to bookmark your SCORM lesson_location.

Comment: You can also add this script to your SCORM content. It will convert SCORM to xAPI based on the SCORM Profile rules. https://github.com/adlnet/SCORM-to-xAPI-Wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Okay .... I read the XAPI docs again... Turns out ... Xapi is like "I did this"

Where I is the actor , did is the Verb & this is the Activity

So the Scorm `API.LMSSetValue("cmi.core.lesson_location", currentPage)`;  ...

Could be the following in xApi

```
{
    "actor": {
        "objectType": "Agent"
    },
    "verb": {
        "id": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/completed",
        "display": {
            "en-US": "completed"
        }
    },
    "object": {
        "id": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/example",
        "definition": {
            "name": {
                "en-US": "Example Activity"
            },
            "description": {
                "en-US": "Example activity description"
            }
        },
        "objectType": "Activity"
    }
}
```

Please correct where I am wrong